# How is a substrate address, or multisig address, calcluated from private key?

Tags: cryptography, address

What are the (high-level) steps to, firstly, create a substrate address from a *private* key and secondly, to create a m-of-n multisig address?

A description similar to this image would be just about my level ;)

[image: BTC address generation flowchart]

Answer (score 3):

The Substrate address is actually derived from the public key:

> For most networks, the public key associated with an account is how
> that account is identified on the network and is used as the
> destination address for transactions. However, Substrate-based chains
> use the underlying public key to derive one or more public addresses.
> Instead of using the public key directly, Substrate allows you
> to generate multiple addresses and address formats for an account.

- https://docs.substrate.io/main-docs/fundamentals/accounts-addresses-keys

> In Substrate-based networks, the sr25519 encoded keys are used to produce SS58 addresses as the public keys for interacting with the blockchain.

- https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/subkey

Additionally, Substrate has a multi-format address wrapper for on-chain accounts:

```rs
pub enum MultiAddress<AccountId, AccountIndex> {
    /// It's an account ID (pubkey).
    Id(AccountId),
    /// It's an account index.
    Index(#[codec(compact)] AccountIndex),
    /// It's some arbitrary raw bytes.
    Raw(Vec<u8>),
    /// It's a 32 byte representation.
    Address32([u8; 32]),
    /// Its a 20 byte representation.
    Address20([u8; 20]),
}
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/028ee356720d9b8de9995acae93de68af4ef8ece/primitives/runtime/src/multiaddress.rs#L26-L37

You can see this gives support to 20 bytes, 32 bytes, arbitrary raw bytes, and you could even have a simple custom index number to represent the address.

Substrate is highly configurable and supports a number of different signature schemes e.g. ed25519 (Edwards), sr25519 (schnorrkel), ecdsa (non-Bitcoin compatible), and it is not limited to these.

To see the process of generating keys in Substrate:

- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/trusted-network/#generate-your-account-and-keys

More info can be found here:

- https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-cryptography
- https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-keys
- https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-accounts#address-generation-derivation-and-portability
- https://polkadot.js.org/docs/keyring/start/ss58#how-is-the-encoding-done

As far as how a multisig address is generated, I recommend looking at this code here:

1. https://polkadot.js.org/docs/util-crypto/examples/create-multisig
2. https://github.com/polkadot-js/build-deno.land/blob/ac5fab607364eda37099f2d08ec1bb5ecc75402d/util-crypto/address/keyMulti.ts#L15-L24